# progressbar AAC android issue

Tags: android, progress, android-progressbar, aac

I am trying to make a progress bar work using AAC with the code bellow, but I got audioBufferSizeMs constantly round and round: 
i.e. audioBufferSizeMs = 700.0, audioBufferSizeMs = 1250.0, audioBufferSizeMs = 825.0
so my bar is like 700/1500 all the time. (audioBufferCapacityMs= 1500).
700/1500, 1250/1500, 825/1500. Any advice please.

```
public void playerPCMFeedBuffer( final boolean isPlaying,
                                 final int audioBufferSizeMs, final int audioBufferCapacityMs ) {

    uiHandler.post( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            progress.setProgress( audioBufferSizeMs * progress.getMax() / audioBufferCapacityMs );
            if (isPlaying) txtStatus.setText( R.string.text_playing );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where does `audioBufferSizeMs` come from?  (how was it computed?)

Comment: I get from this https://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/source/browse/trunk/player/src/com/spoledge/aacplay/AACPlayerActivity.java
Everything is working fine except the progressbar.

Comment: Are you streaming live radio? If so then you dont need/want to create a seekbar. Each "piece" of live stream bytes is gone once you hear it. To seek an actual complete & stored track just needs a tutorial from google search..

Comment: Not the live streaming, but just file from server MP3.